# Center three buttons

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout in a sidebar:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="center">
        <div>button one</div>
        <div>button two</div>
        <div>button three</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to center these three buttons by setting the `center` width = 100% and the buttons `divs` to be 33%.

```
.sidebar {
    width: 300px
}
.center {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
.center div {
    width: 33%;
}
```

However, I'd like to layout to remain centered when I only have two buttons:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="center">
        <div>button one</div>
        <div>button two</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So that the two buttons would be in the center (i.e., indent both buttons 16.66% from the right and left edges, in absence of the third button).

How would I accomplish this with a purely css solution?

Comment: It would help to see the CSS you're applying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need:
http://jsfiddle.net/HFaTW/

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="center">
        <div>button one</div>
        <div>button two</div>
        <div>button three</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar{
    width:400px;
}

.center{
    background-color:#f9f9f9;
    text-align:center;
}

.center div{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-right:5px;
    color:#FFF;
    background-color:darkgray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is setting `text-align: center` on the .center element and `display: inline-block` on the divs inside - demo http://dabblet.com/gist/3118171

The HTML & CSS (both cases):

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="center">
        <div>button one</div><div>button two</div><div>button three</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="center">
        <div>button one</div><div>button two</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

.

```
.sidebar {
    width: 40%;
}
.center {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.center div {
    width: 33.33%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**Note**: You should not have any kind of whitespace between the closing tag `</div>` and the opening tag of the next `<div>`